# Large Graphs: NetworkX distributed alternative

Tags: machine-learning, graphs, distributed

I have built some implementations using `NetworkX`(graph Python module) native algorithms in which I output some attributes which I use them for classification purposes.

I want to scale it to a distributed environment. I have seen many approaches like `neo4j`, `Graphx`, `GraphLab`. However, I am quite new to this, thus I want to ask, which of them would be easy to locally apply graph algorithms (ex. node centrality measures), preferably using Python. To be more specific, which available option is closer related to `NetworkX` (easy installation, premade functions/algorithms, ML wise)?

Comment: I suggest looking into Spark's [GraphFrames](http://graphframes.github.io). It's Scala (not a bad thing!) but uses the familiar dataframe paradigm.

Comment: @Emre Yes indeed, I had a quick look. I can see that supports some Python, however, I suppose that the functionalities are less than using Scala. Btw, if you know, just to make sure, the licensing for GraphFrames is totally free? even for commercial purposes?

Comment: It's published under the [Apache License](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes/blob/master/LICENSE) ([FAQ](http://www.whitesourcesoftware.com/whitesource-blog/top-10-apache-license-questions-answered/))

Comment: @Emre Thank you very much and especially for you valuable answer, GraphFrames seems a legit solution.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Good , old and unsolved question! Distributed processing of large graphs as far as I know (speaking as a graph guy) has 2 different approaches, with the knowledge of Big Data frameworks or without it.

[SNAP](http://snap.stanford.edu/) library from Jure Leskovec group at  Stanford which is originally in C++ but also has a Python API (please check if you need to use C++ API or Python does the job you want to do). Using snap you can do many things on massive networks without any special knowledge of Big Data technologies. So I would say the easiest one.

Using Apache Graphx is wonderful only if you have experience in Scala because there is no Python thing for that. It comes with a large stack of built in algorithms including centrality measures. So the second easiest in case you know Scala.

Long time ago when I looked at GraphLab it was commercial. Now I see it goes open source so maybe you know better than me but from my out-dated knowledge I remember that it does not support a wide range of algorithms and if you need an algorithm which is not there it might get complicated to implement. On the other hand it uses Python which is cool. After all please check it again as my knowledge is for 3 years ago.

If you are familiar with Big Data frameworks and working with them, [Giraph](http://giraph.apache.org/quick_start.html) and [Gradoop](https://github.com/dbs-leipzig/gradoop) are 2 great options. Both do fantastic jobs but you need to know some Big Data architecture e.g. working with a hadoop platform.

### PS

1) I have used simple NetworkX and multiprocessing to distributedly process DBLP network with 400,000 nodes and it worked well, so you need to know HOW BIG your graph is.

2) After all, I think SNAP library is a handy thing.

Comment: Thank you very much, I did not know about the SNAP library. This seems a handy option. BTW would you now out of curiosity if SNAP scales with Spark?

Comment: Also, about the graphLab me too, do not know if it is totally free, I read somewhere that you can get granted 1 year full, for academic purposes only. Btw I had found this interesting podcast about Dato if would be of interest [O'reilly podcast](https://www.oreilly.com/ideas/building-and-deploying-large-scale-machine-learning-applications)

Comment: I wouldn't invest in graphlab now that [Apple bought it](http://www.geekwire.com/2016/exclusive-apple-acquires-turi-major-exit-seattle-based-machine-learning-ai-startup/).

Comment: I actually used SNAP only for simple experiments on medium-size graphs so I do not know if it scales with Spark but they have a QA system to ask your question. I suggest to contact THEM directly. @PhilipC.

Comment: While GraphX isn't directly available in Python APIs, Apache Spark does now make that functionality available through the newer GraphFrames package. See https://graphframes.github.io/ and https://databricks.com/blog/2016/03/03/introducing-graphframes.html

Comment: I have not built but looked at SNAP documentation. I have built with Neo4J and OrientDb, and GraphLab for analytics on ML. For me, if you have to build a final product, Neo4J and OrientDb offer a more robust environment. For analytics, GraphLab is very flexible. I'd like to try SNAP more, I have not found clarity to how to query for nodes based on their attributes, while good for analysis a network as a whole. I'd like to try combining SNAP with a web server, e.g. python flask. With networkx and flask, I was able to fit a web service on a normal machine, while with graphDb >= 8GB ram.

Answer (score 6):

In this present moment, Apache has develop a powerfull API called PySpark. And you can setup [Graphframes](http://graphframes.github.io/graphframes/docs/_site/quick-start.html) directly from `pyspark` command line. Launch from you shell terminal:

```
pyspark --packages graphframes:graphframes:0.6.0-spark2.3-s_2.11
```

and you can develop your code entirely in `python` using `graphframes` API. Try the following example code

```
# Create a Vertex DataFrame with unique ID column "id"
v = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", "Alice", 34),
    ("b", "Bob", 36),
    ("c", "Charlie", 30),
    ], ["id", "name", "age"])

# Create an Edge DataFrame with "src" and "dst" columns
e = sqlContext.createDataFrame([
    ("a", "b", "friend"),
    ("b", "c", "follow"),
    ("c", "b", "follow"),
    ], ["src", "dst", "relationship"])

# Create a GraphFrame
from graphframes import *
g = GraphFrame(v, e)

# Query: Get in-degree of each vertex.
g.inDegrees.show()

# Query: Count the number of "follow" connections in the graph.
g.edges.filter("relationship = 'follow'").count()

# Run PageRank algorithm, and show results.
results = g.pageRank(resetProbability=0.01, maxIter=20)
results.vertices.select("id", "pagerank").show()
```

Above we could calculate `pageRank` from graph `g`. There are several algorithms already implemented on PySpark with Graphframes. I hope I've helped.

Answer (score 1):

### GraphBLAS: graph algorithms in the language of linear algebra

There has been a lot of radical innovation in 2017-2020 in terms of distributed and parallel graph algorithms.

[GraphBLAS](https://github.com/DrTimothyAldenDavis/GraphBLAS) itself provides the building blocks for creating more advanced algorithms.

If you want more sophisticated algorithms, like PageRank and ConnectedCompoments, you can check out [LAGraph](https://github.com/GraphBLAS/LAGraph): a library plus a test harness for collecting algorithms that use the GraphBLAS.

Oh, and check out [GraphBLAST by gunrock](https://github.com/gunrock/graphblast), in case you are interested in running graph algorithms on your GPU.

Since you are using Python, you probably want to use [GraphBLAS for Python](https://github.com/michelp/pygraphblas)

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same question, I found a distributed alternative, that has compatible api with networkx called [GraphScope](https://graphscope.io/docs/reference/networkx/index.html). They're using an in-memory immutable data manager called [vineyard](https://v6d.io/), my current setup is loading data from a cloud blob file (s3) into GraphScope graph (which is networkx compatiable) and initializing GraphScope session.

All I changed in my notebooks are replacing `import networkx as nx` with `import graphscope.nx as nx`